# Microsoft Graph api not returning new pages added for Onenote Personal account

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

We have Onenote app to access MS Graph apis, with which we try to resend the Onenote files. When we request the pages from “https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages" or “https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/SECTION_ID/pages" api It does not work for Onenote Personal accounts. Though it works fine with Onenote Business account.

For Personal Onenote Account (Broken API)

[image]
API: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/0-9F68E2F383B568C7!121/pages

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('kharemohit786%40gmail.com')/onenote/sections('0-9F68E2F383B568C7%21121')/pages",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "0-4f65ff1584f34ff1a4746d59be93ac3a!11-9F68E2F383B568C7!121",
            "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/kharemohit786@gmail.com/onenote/pages/0-4f65ff1584f34ff1a4746d59be93ac3a!11-9F68E2F383B568C7!121",
            "createdDateTime": "2011-04-22T19:07:12Z",
            "title": "dgsfdvxcsdf",
            "createdByAppId": "",
            "contentUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/kharemohit786@gmail.com/onenote/pages/0-4f65ff1584f34ff1a4746d59be93ac3a!11-9F68E2F383B568C7!121/content",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-03-19T07:34:33Z",
            "links": {
                "oneNoteClientUrl": {
                    "href": "onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/9f68e2f383b568c7/Notebook1/Untitled%20Section.one#dgsfdvxcsdf&section-id=12f5bdd7-01fe-406d-bbe0-19ab0fff7015&page-id=9f1fc8a9-26a6-45f7-93d9-f3cbc9ce0ee9&end"
                },
                "oneNoteWebUrl": {
                    "href": "https://onedrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=9f68e2f383b568c7&page=edit&resid=9F68E2F383B568C7!120&parId=9F68E2F383B568C7!116&wd=target%28Untitled%20Section.one%7C12f5bdd7-01fe-406d-bbe0-19ab0fff7015%2Fdgsfdvxcsdf%7C9f1fc8a9-26a6-45f7-93d9-f3cbc9ce0ee9%2F%29"
                }
            },
            "parentSection@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('kharemohit786%40gmail.com')/onenote/sections('0-9F68E2F383B568C7%21121')/pages('0-4f65ff1584f34ff1a4746d59be93ac3a%2111-9F68E2F383B568C7%21121')/parentSection/$entity",
            "parentSection": {
                "id": "0-9F68E2F383B568C7!121",
                "displayName": "Untitled Section",
                "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/kharemohit786@gmail.com/onenote/sections/0-9F68E2F383B568C7!121"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "0-90d797088a290f1c18bec3b14f1e15b5!1-9F68E2F383B568C7!121",
            "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/kharemohit786@gmail.com/onenote/pages/0-90d797088a290f1c18bec3b14f1e15b5!1-9F68E2F383B568C7!121",
            "createdDateTime": "2019-10-10T06:37:45Z",
            "title": "Printout",
            "createdByAppId": "",
            "contentUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/kharemohit786@gmail.com/onenote/pages/0-90d797088a290f1c18bec3b14f1e15b5!1-9F68E2F383B568C7!121/content",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-10-10T06:39:43Z",
            "links": {
                "oneNoteClientUrl": {
                    "href": "onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/9f68e2f383b568c7/Notebook1/Untitled%20Section.one#Printout&section-id=12f5bdd7-01fe-406d-bbe0-19ab0fff7015&page-id=81c2e2dd-e51c-4046-9b89-397915d8f5b4&end"
                },
                "oneNoteWebUrl": {
                    "href": "https://onedrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=9f68e2f383b568c7&page=edit&resid=9F68E2F383B568C7!120&parId=9F68E2F383B568C7!116&wd=target%28Untitled%20Section.one%7C12f5bdd7-01fe-406d-bbe0-19ab0fff7015%2FPrintout%7C81c2e2dd-e51c-4046-9b89-397915d8f5b4%2F%29"
                }
            },
            "parentSection@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('kharemohit786%40gmail.com')/onenote/sections('0-9F68E2F383B568C7%21121')/pages('0-90d797088a290f1c18bec3b14f1e15b5%211-9F68E2F383B568C7%21121')/parentSection/$entity",
            "parentSection": {
                "id": "0-9F68E2F383B568C7!121",
                "displayName": "Untitled Section",
                "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/kharemohit786@gmail.com/onenote/sections/0-9F68E2F383B568C7!121"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For Business Onenote Account (working API)-

[image]
API: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3/pages

Response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3')/onenote/sections('1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/pages",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "1-642020d2436d42c6bdba64e92d810e58!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
            "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/pages/1-642020d2436d42c6bdba64e92d810e58!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-04-03T09:25:31Z",
            "title": "New doc added test1",
            "createdByAppId": "",
            "contentUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/pages/1-642020d2436d42c6bdba64e92d810e58!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3/content",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-04-03T09:25:45Z",
            "links": {
                "oneNoteClientUrl": {
                    "href": "onenote:https://alpsenseinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mkhare_alpsenseinc_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/NoteBook_6/Untitled%20Section.one#New%20doc%20added%20test1&section-id=9c1c44d4-dd39-4e93-8f06-5f1ac9fe040e&page-id=ad6cad08-2a50-425f-a994-724accbe40a7&end"
                },
                "oneNoteWebUrl": {
                    "href": "https://alpsenseinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mkhare_alpsenseinc_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/NoteBook_6?wd=target%28Untitled%20Section.one%7C9c1c44d4-dd39-4e93-8f06-5f1ac9fe040e%2FNew%20doc%20added%20test1%7Cad6cad08-2a50-425f-a994-724accbe40a7%2F%29"
                }
            },
            "parentSection@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3')/onenote/sections('1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/pages('1-642020d2436d42c6bdba64e92d810e58%2113-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/parentSection/$entity",
            "parentSection": {
                "id": "1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
                "displayName": "Untitled Section",
                "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/sections/1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "1-f5a5006894cd46479b735eb97df3f049!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
            "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/pages/1-f5a5006894cd46479b735eb97df3f049!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-03-06T11:58:18Z",
            "title": "New page rename",
            "createdByAppId": "",
            "contentUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/pages/1-f5a5006894cd46479b735eb97df3f049!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3/content",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-03-19T07:28:15Z",
            "links": {
                "oneNoteClientUrl": {
                    "href": "onenote:https://alpsenseinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mkhare_alpsenseinc_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/NoteBook_6/Untitled%20Section.one#New%20page%20rename&section-id=9c1c44d4-dd39-4e93-8f06-5f1ac9fe040e&page-id=112d8106-98b3-4b29-86df-c12f31d5029f&end"
                },
                "oneNoteWebUrl": {
                    "href": "https://alpsenseinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mkhare_alpsenseinc_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/NoteBook_6?wd=target%28Untitled%20Section.one%7C9c1c44d4-dd39-4e93-8f06-5f1ac9fe040e%2FNew%20page%20rename%7C112d8106-98b3-4b29-86df-c12f31d5029f%2F%29"
                }
            },
            "parentSection@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3')/onenote/sections('1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/pages('1-f5a5006894cd46479b735eb97df3f049%2113-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/parentSection/$entity",
            "parentSection": {
                "id": "1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
                "displayName": "Untitled Section",
                "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/sections/1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "1-c7ffe1d97ac64e65bb7b04c955978b5f!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
            "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/pages/1-c7ffe1d97ac64e65bb7b04c955978b5f!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-03-03T16:25:03Z",
            "title": "New again something",
            "createdByAppId": "",
            "contentUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/pages/1-c7ffe1d97ac64e65bb7b04c955978b5f!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3/content",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-03-03T16:30:52Z",
            "links": {
                "oneNoteClientUrl": {
                    "href": "onenote:https://alpsenseinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mkhare_alpsenseinc_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/NoteBook_6/Untitled%20Section.one#New%20again%20something&section-id=9c1c44d4-dd39-4e93-8f06-5f1ac9fe040e&page-id=614a5275-8fcc-4899-afd5-9327ef7dafb2&end"
                },
                "oneNoteWebUrl": {
                    "href": "https://alpsenseinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mkhare_alpsenseinc_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/NoteBook_6?wd=target%28Untitled%20Section.one%7C9c1c44d4-dd39-4e93-8f06-5f1ac9fe040e%2FNew%20again%20something%7C614a5275-8fcc-4899-afd5-9327ef7dafb2%2F%29"
                }
            },
            "parentSection@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3')/onenote/sections('1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/pages('1-c7ffe1d97ac64e65bb7b04c955978b5f%2113-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/parentSection/$entity",
            "parentSection": {
                "id": "1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
                "displayName": "Untitled Section",
                "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/sections/1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "1-8b46dcec9c024088873ed5c65ed57e82!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
            "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/pages/1-8b46dcec9c024088873ed5c65ed57e82!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-03-03T15:33:33Z",
            "title": "Test bg sync",
            "createdByAppId": "",
            "contentUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/pages/1-8b46dcec9c024088873ed5c65ed57e82!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3/content",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-03-03T15:33:40Z",
            "links": {
                "oneNoteClientUrl": {
                    "href": "onenote:https://alpsenseinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mkhare_alpsenseinc_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/NoteBook_6/Untitled%20Section.one#Test%20bg%20sync&section-id=9c1c44d4-dd39-4e93-8f06-5f1ac9fe040e&page-id=9af9f649-cbe0-4e52-88a5-32d742426016&end"
                },
                "oneNoteWebUrl": {
                    "href": "https://alpsenseinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mkhare_alpsenseinc_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/NoteBook_6?wd=target%28Untitled%20Section.one%7C9c1c44d4-dd39-4e93-8f06-5f1ac9fe040e%2FTest%20bg%20sync%7C9af9f649-cbe0-4e52-88a5-32d742426016%2F%29"
                }
            },
            "parentSection@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3')/onenote/sections('1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/pages('1-8b46dcec9c024088873ed5c65ed57e82%2113-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/parentSection/$entity",
            "parentSection": {
                "id": "1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
                "displayName": "Untitled Section",
                "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/sections/1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "1-ecdfefa08b0c47acb03c6ef303c82751!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
            "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/pages/1-ecdfefa08b0c47acb03c6ef303c82751!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-03-03T15:32:57Z",
            "title": "",
            "createdByAppId": "",
            "contentUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/pages/1-ecdfefa08b0c47acb03c6ef303c82751!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3/content",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-03-03T15:32:57Z",
            "links": {
                "oneNoteClientUrl": {
                    "href": "onenote:https://alpsenseinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mkhare_alpsenseinc_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/NoteBook_6/Untitled%20Section.one#&section-id=9c1c44d4-dd39-4e93-8f06-5f1ac9fe040e&page-id=934dc71a-3143-4488-a3b1-51da3c546684&end"
                },
                "oneNoteWebUrl": {
                    "href": "https://alpsenseinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mkhare_alpsenseinc_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/NoteBook_6?wd=target%28Untitled%20Section.one%7C9c1c44d4-dd39-4e93-8f06-5f1ac9fe040e%2F%7C934dc71a-3143-4488-a3b1-51da3c546684%2F%29"
                }
            },
            "parentSection@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3')/onenote/sections('1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/pages('1-ecdfefa08b0c47acb03c6ef303c82751%2113-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/parentSection/$entity",
            "parentSection": {
                "id": "1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
                "displayName": "Untitled Section",
                "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/sections/1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "1-80d91f26132e42e6946b900e14db5127!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
            "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/pages/1-80d91f26132e42e6946b900e14db5127!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
            "createdDateTime": "2019-12-05T13:48:31Z",
            "title": "New page created 5/12/2019",
            "createdByAppId": "",
            "contentUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/pages/1-80d91f26132e42e6946b900e14db5127!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3/content",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-12-05T13:49:00Z",
            "links": {
                "oneNoteClientUrl": {
                    "href": "onenote:https://alpsenseinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mkhare_alpsenseinc_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/NoteBook_6/Untitled%20Section.one#New%20page%20created%205%2F12%2F2019&section-id=9c1c44d4-dd39-4e93-8f06-5f1ac9fe040e&page-id=2c126962-ca69-40af-aa0b-ce1767a0108f&end"
                },
                "oneNoteWebUrl": {
                    "href": "https://alpsenseinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mkhare_alpsenseinc_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/NoteBook_6?wd=target%28Untitled%20Section.one%7C9c1c44d4-dd39-4e93-8f06-5f1ac9fe040e%2FNew%20page%20created%205%5C%2F12%5C%2F2019%7C2c126962-ca69-40af-aa0b-ce1767a0108f%2F%29"
                }
            },
            "parentSection@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3')/onenote/sections('1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/pages('1-80d91f26132e42e6946b900e14db5127%2113-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/parentSection/$entity",
            "parentSection": {
                "id": "1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
                "displayName": "Untitled Section",
                "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/sections/1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "1-4fa3480b7613438da93c5d20498b092c!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
            "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/pages/1-4fa3480b7613438da93c5d20498b092c!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
            "createdDateTime": "2019-11-28T07:05:52Z",
            "title": "NB6_New Doc2",
            "createdByAppId": "",
            "contentUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/pages/1-4fa3480b7613438da93c5d20498b092c!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3/content",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-11-28T07:06:13Z",
            "links": {
                "oneNoteClientUrl": {
                    "href": "onenote:https://alpsenseinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mkhare_alpsenseinc_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/NoteBook_6/Untitled%20Section.one#NB6_New%20Doc2&section-id=9c1c44d4-dd39-4e93-8f06-5f1ac9fe040e&page-id=e37b52c4-f516-4eee-ad17-09f62b980c67&end"
                },
                "oneNoteWebUrl": {
                    "href": "https://alpsenseinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mkhare_alpsenseinc_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/NoteBook_6?wd=target%28Untitled%20Section.one%7C9c1c44d4-dd39-4e93-8f06-5f1ac9fe040e%2FNB6_New%20Doc2%7Ce37b52c4-f516-4eee-ad17-09f62b980c67%2F%29"
                }
            },
            "parentSection@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3')/onenote/sections('1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/pages('1-4fa3480b7613438da93c5d20498b092c%2113-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/parentSection/$entity",
            "parentSection": {
                "id": "1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
                "displayName": "Untitled Section",
                "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/sections/1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "1-550a7f89915841b18d3cb34f0f3bd2b8!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
            "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/pages/1-550a7f89915841b18d3cb34f0f3bd2b8!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
            "createdDateTime": "2019-10-30T10:24:08Z",
            "title": "New Doc 01_edited-ON",
            "createdByAppId": "",
            "contentUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/pages/1-550a7f89915841b18d3cb34f0f3bd2b8!13-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3/content",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-11-07T10:07:33Z",
            "links": {
                "oneNoteClientUrl": {
                    "href": "onenote:https://alpsenseinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mkhare_alpsenseinc_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/NoteBook_6/Untitled%20Section.one#New%20Doc%2001_edited-ON&section-id=9c1c44d4-dd39-4e93-8f06-5f1ac9fe040e&page-id=c54152ef-e499-4956-998f-e256c06e3e89&end"
                },
                "oneNoteWebUrl": {
                    "href": "https://alpsenseinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mkhare_alpsenseinc_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/NoteBook_6?wd=target%28Untitled%20Section.one%7C9c1c44d4-dd39-4e93-8f06-5f1ac9fe040e%2FNew%20Doc%2001_edited-ON%7Cc54152ef-e499-4956-998f-e256c06e3e89%2F%29"
                }
            },
            "parentSection@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3')/onenote/sections('1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/pages('1-550a7f89915841b18d3cb34f0f3bd2b8%2113-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3')/parentSection/$entity",
            "parentSection": {
                "id": "1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3",
                "displayName": "Untitled Section",
                "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/90663365-558e-4b96-9648-bc10311bc5e3/onenote/sections/1-c3157ac3-363f-48cc-a251-f1eb6599b8e3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same call in the personal account and it worked for me as shown below. In order to call this API you need to have the below [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onenote-list-pages?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions).

[Please see the permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlPtv.png)

This is the Http call I used.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303/pages

[Please see this Image for my personal onenote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPe4R.png)

This is my JSON data.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('vshivakeshavvarma%40yahoo.com')/onenote/sections('0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1%211303')/pages",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!242-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
            "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/pages/0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!242-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-04-08T13:15:11Z",
            "title": "bvnvmb",
            "createdByAppId": "",
            "contentUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/pages/0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!242-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303/content",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-04-08T13:15:13Z",
            "links": {
                "oneNoteClientUrl": {
                    "href": "onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/28d742e0f8d9cef1/Documents/shivakeshav%20varma's%20Notebook/Untitled.one#bvnvmb&section-id=3c96391f-2718-4930-b5fc-3e333ef81dea&page-id=1e1a93ca-ddff-4faf-8386-0dd3601b6769&end"
                },
                "oneNoteWebUrl": {
                    "href": "https://onedrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=28d742e0f8d9cef1&page=edit&resid=28D742E0F8D9CEF1!967&parId=28D742E0F8D9CEF1!332&wd=target%28Untitled.one%7C3c96391f-2718-4930-b5fc-3e333ef81dea%2Fbvnvmb%7C1e1a93ca-ddff-4faf-8386-0dd3601b6769%2F%29"
                }
            },
            "parentSection@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('vshivakeshavvarma%40yahoo.com')/onenote/sections('0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1%211303')/pages('0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22%21242-28D742E0F8D9CEF1%211303')/parentSection/$entity",
            "parentSection": {
                "id": "0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
                "displayName": "Untitled Section",
                "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/sections/0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!196-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
            "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/pages/0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!196-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-04-08T13:15:07Z",
            "title": ",jklkjljkl",
            "createdByAppId": "",
            "contentUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/pages/0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!196-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303/content",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-04-08T13:15:09Z",
            "links": {
                "oneNoteClientUrl": {
                    "href": "onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/28d742e0f8d9cef1/Documents/shivakeshav%20varma's%20Notebook/Untitled.one#%2Cjklkjljkl&section-id=3c96391f-2718-4930-b5fc-3e333ef81dea&page-id=3710a622-8c53-49a3-a476-2a5455ea86c2&end"
                },
                "oneNoteWebUrl": {
                    "href": "https://onedrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=28d742e0f8d9cef1&page=edit&resid=28D742E0F8D9CEF1!967&parId=28D742E0F8D9CEF1!332&wd=target%28Untitled.one%7C3c96391f-2718-4930-b5fc-3e333ef81dea%2F%2Cjklkjljkl%7C3710a622-8c53-49a3-a476-2a5455ea86c2%2F%29"
                }
            },
            "parentSection@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('vshivakeshavvarma%40yahoo.com')/onenote/sections('0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1%211303')/pages('0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22%21196-28D742E0F8D9CEF1%211303')/parentSection/$entity",
            "parentSection": {
                "id": "0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
                "displayName": "Untitled Section",
                "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/sections/0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!157-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
            "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/pages/0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!157-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-04-08T13:15:04Z",
            "title": "rtutyutyu",
            "createdByAppId": "",
            "contentUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/pages/0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!157-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303/content",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-04-08T13:15:06Z",
            "links": {
                "oneNoteClientUrl": {
                    "href": "onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/28d742e0f8d9cef1/Documents/shivakeshav%20varma's%20Notebook/Untitled.one#rtutyutyu&section-id=3c96391f-2718-4930-b5fc-3e333ef81dea&page-id=69c5da13-dc8c-47bc-8059-696662c61c08&end"
                },
                "oneNoteWebUrl": {
                    "href": "https://onedrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=28d742e0f8d9cef1&page=edit&resid=28D742E0F8D9CEF1!967&parId=28D742E0F8D9CEF1!332&wd=target%28Untitled.one%7C3c96391f-2718-4930-b5fc-3e333ef81dea%2Frtutyutyu%7C69c5da13-dc8c-47bc-8059-696662c61c08%2F%29"
                }
            },
            "parentSection@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('vshivakeshavvarma%40yahoo.com')/onenote/sections('0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1%211303')/pages('0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22%21157-28D742E0F8D9CEF1%211303')/parentSection/$entity",
            "parentSection": {
                "id": "0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
                "displayName": "Untitled Section",
                "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/sections/0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!117-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
            "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/pages/0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!117-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-04-08T13:15:01Z",
            "title": "vcbnbvn",
            "createdByAppId": "",
            "contentUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/pages/0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!117-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303/content",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-04-08T13:15:02Z",
            "links": {
                "oneNoteClientUrl": {
                    "href": "onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/28d742e0f8d9cef1/Documents/shivakeshav%20varma's%20Notebook/Untitled.one#vcbnbvn&section-id=3c96391f-2718-4930-b5fc-3e333ef81dea&page-id=8f153df3-5b57-491d-9c38-62483936c386&end"
                },
                "oneNoteWebUrl": {
                    "href": "https://onedrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=28d742e0f8d9cef1&page=edit&resid=28D742E0F8D9CEF1!967&parId=28D742E0F8D9CEF1!332&wd=target%28Untitled.one%7C3c96391f-2718-4930-b5fc-3e333ef81dea%2Fvcbnbvn%7C8f153df3-5b57-491d-9c38-62483936c386%2F%29"
                }
            },
            "parentSection@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('vshivakeshavvarma%40yahoo.com')/onenote/sections('0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1%211303')/pages('0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22%21117-28D742E0F8D9CEF1%211303')/parentSection/$entity",
            "parentSection": {
                "id": "0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
                "displayName": "Untitled Section",
                "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/sections/0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!14-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
            "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/pages/0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!14-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-04-08T13:12:59Z",
            "title": "sdfsadfdsf",
            "createdByAppId": "",
            "contentUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/pages/0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!14-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303/content",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-04-08T13:14:59Z",
            "links": {
                "oneNoteClientUrl": {
                    "href": "onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/28d742e0f8d9cef1/Documents/shivakeshav%20varma's%20Notebook/Untitled.one#sdfsadfdsf&section-id=3c96391f-2718-4930-b5fc-3e333ef81dea&page-id=8faaae54-84e2-4531-a832-7fb9f3cbb390&end"
                },
                "oneNoteWebUrl": {
                    "href": "https://onedrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=28d742e0f8d9cef1&page=edit&resid=28D742E0F8D9CEF1!967&parId=28D742E0F8D9CEF1!332&wd=target%28Untitled.one%7C3c96391f-2718-4930-b5fc-3e333ef81dea%2Fsdfsadfdsf%7C8faaae54-84e2-4531-a832-7fb9f3cbb390%2F%29"
                }
            },
            "parentSection@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('vshivakeshavvarma%40yahoo.com')/onenote/sections('0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1%211303')/pages('0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22%2114-28D742E0F8D9CEF1%211303')/parentSection/$entity",
            "parentSection": {
                "id": "0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
                "displayName": "Untitled Section",
                "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/sections/0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!64-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
            "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/pages/0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!64-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-04-08T13:14:52Z",
            "title": "asdfasfdsf",
            "createdByAppId": "",
            "contentUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/pages/0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22!64-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303/content",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-04-08T13:14:55Z",
            "links": {
                "oneNoteClientUrl": {
                    "href": "onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/28d742e0f8d9cef1/Documents/shivakeshav%20varma's%20Notebook/Untitled.one#asdfasfdsf&section-id=3c96391f-2718-4930-b5fc-3e333ef81dea&page-id=92391e17-67fc-405e-87ad-881ee761bc35&end"
                },
                "oneNoteWebUrl": {
                    "href": "https://onedrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=28d742e0f8d9cef1&page=edit&resid=28D742E0F8D9CEF1!967&parId=28D742E0F8D9CEF1!332&wd=target%28Untitled.one%7C3c96391f-2718-4930-b5fc-3e333ef81dea%2Fasdfasfdsf%7C92391e17-67fc-405e-87ad-881ee761bc35%2F%29"
                }
            },
            "parentSection@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('vshivakeshavvarma%40yahoo.com')/onenote/sections('0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1%211303')/pages('0-22322a43e71f42febe8ca4e0e6caff22%2164-28D742E0F8D9CEF1%211303')/parentSection/$entity",
            "parentSection": {
                "id": "0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303",
                "displayName": "Untitled Section",
                "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vshivakeshavvarma@yahoo.com/onenote/sections/0-28D742E0F8D9CEF1!1303"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I verified there are no issues with the permissions I have given while calling these APIs, please check the screenshot in below graph explorer permissions box-
https://i.imgur.com/pVp2XKj.png

Could you ensure you checked this on Onenote personal account and not on business account?

Comment: thanks for checking, adding to the above. If its personal account only you have to try for adding new notes and check the response, only newly created notes does not reflect.

Comment: @khare Thanks for replying. As I said I am using the personal account, you can see that in the JSON data which I provided. I have also reproduced the issue and facing the same problem. Will check with the PG team and get back soon.

Comment: Thanks Shiva, it did not look like from the comment that you were able to reproduce the issue. Though please respond back when you have some solution for this, we have many users impacted because of this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any update on the above? 
Given we are not seeing this for new sections created this is only replicable when new pages are added into a section, this is becoming crucial to know any new upadtes inside a Notebook. It would be relally helpful if you could give us any other alternative for this or some timeline on the issue to get resolved? Thanks.